# Jenkins error sh: 0: Can't open label:/ sh: 0: Can't open script: when trying to execute SOAPUI commandline

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, soapui, ready-api

I am tring to run the SoapUI TestRunner via a commandline in Jenkins. This is the SoapUI TestRunner commandline:

```
"/home/able/readyapi/installation/bin/testrunner.sh" -spayments-chain -r -a -j -f${WORKSPACE} "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML -Enn-0716 "-TTestCase jenkins_test" /home/able/jenkins/workspace/REGRESSION_0716/test_automation
```

I generated a shell script in Jenkins' Pipeline Syntax leading to this shell script:

```
sh script: '"/home/able/readyapi/installation/bin/testrunner.sh" -spayments-chain -r -a -j -f${WORKSPACE} "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML -Enn-0716 "-TTestCase jenkins_test" /home/able/jenkins/workspace/REGRESSION_0716/test_automation'
```

This gets me the following error:

```
sh: 0: Can't open script:
```

Can I anybody tell me with this information what I am doing wrong? Please let me know if you need more info. I am not very familiar with linux and shell.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be simply

```
sh '"/home/able/readyapi/installation/bin/testrunner.sh" -spayments-chain -r -a -j -f${WORKSPACE} "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML -Enn-0716 "-TTestCase jenkins_test" /home/able/jenkins/workspace/REGRESSION_0716/test_automation'
```

so it is quite literally telling you that `script:` should not be there.

The quoting around the first argument is batshit crazy, but not incorrect.  It is equivalent to the more idiomatic

```
sh '/home/able/readyapi/installation/bin/testrunner.sh -spayments-chain -r -a -j -f"${WORKSPACE}" "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML -Enn-0716 "-TTestCase jenkins_test" /home/able/jenkins/workspace/REGRESSION_0716/test_automation'
```

You'll notice I added quotes around `-f${WORKSPACE}` as well as removed them around the script's name.  The quotes around `"-RJUnit-Style HTML Report"` look bewildering too, but if it works for you, I guess they are correct. (Maybe it should be `-RJunit-Style "HTML Report"` though? Or `-R"Junit-Style HTML Report"`? And similarly for the `-T` option later on.)

Comment: Hi tripleee, thanks for your input. After using sh '/home/able/readyapi/installation/bin/testrunner.sh -spayments-chain -r -a -j -f"${WORKSPACE}" "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML -Enn-0716 "-TTestCase jenkins_test" /home/able/jenkins/workspace/REGRESSION_0716/test_automation' I now get a "sh: 0: Can't open " message. I think the "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" is correct since I copied that from SoapUI. Do you maybe have other suggestions?

Comment: Just `sh: 0: Can't open ` with nothing after it?  Probably show the entire `pipeline { ... }` anyway (I suggest you edit your question to update it, or maybe ask a new question).